# OneHotEncoder - SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier

Tags: python, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

I do the following:

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
one_hot_encoder = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown=’error’)
```

and I get the following error:

```py
  File "***************", line 37
    one_hot_encoder = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown=’error’)
                                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier
```

How can I fix this?

The `scikit-learn` version which I use is `0.21.3` - I confirmed that by doing:

```py
import sklearn
print('The scikit-learn version is {}.'.format(sklearn.__version__))
```

Comment: I'm not sure but the issue seems to be in your apostrophes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use quotes, **not** apostrophes:

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
```

Incorrect use (with apostrophes):

```py
one_hot_encoder = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown=’error’)
  File "<ipython-input-2-cc1aeb61de22>", line 1
    one_hot_encoder = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown=’error’)
                                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier
```

Correct use (with quotes):

```py
one_hot_encoder = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='error')
# works OK
```

where you can also see that syntax highlighting is your friend (in the second case, `'error'` is correctly recognized as a string, in contrast with the first one).